# Count of active cases on Contact

Tags: apex, controller

I need to get count of active cases where status = active on a contact.If number of active cases are greater than one.Then for each contact need to display the error message .

```
    if(con=='Case') {
              List<Case> caseList=[Select Id, Status,Person_Role__c FROM Case WHERE Person_Role__c IN :selectedID AND Status='Active' ];
  }
```

How to proceed further to get active cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the caseList variable size by using the below code and return the error message.

```
    if(caseList.size()  > 1){
       ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'You have more than one active case'));

}
```

Comment: What exactly you are getting the issue with the above code.

Comment: Just debugged issue was from my side :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use aggregate functions for your requirement.

```
AggregateResult[] groupedResults
  = [SELECT Person_Role__c, COUNT(Id) countId
    FROM Case
    WHERE status = 'Active'
    AND Person_Role__c IN::selectedCYP
    GROUP BY Person_Role__c
    HAVING COUNT(Id)>1];

List<Sting> lstContact = new List<String>();    
for (AggregateResult ar : groupedResults)  {

    lstContact.add((String) ar.get('Person_Role__c'));
    System.debug('Person role' + ar.get('Person_Role__c'));
    System.debug('Count of Case' + ar.get('countId'));  
}
String exceptionStr = 'Following contacts have more than 1 cases ' + String.join(lstContact,',');
```

For more information, refer [Working with SOQL Aggregate Functions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_agg_fns.htm)

Comment: I there any other way other than this..

Comment: may I know whats the issue in this solution? without aggregate function also you can do that, aggregate function is used when we try to do COUNT, MAX, MIN, SUM

Comment: Got my issue fixed Actually I shouldn't use aggregate function because I was already provided by query by business so was checking for alternate solution.Thank you:)